# How to extract specific rows using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My sample dataset. My original dataset contains 40,000 rows and 4 columns.

[image]

I want to extract rows where all sentiment columns are the same (either all positive like Document 2, 5, and 6 or all negative like Document 3).

How can I do this by using python?

Thank you for your suggestions and advice.

Comment: did you solve it or not?

Comment: I made some correction. I used this: negative_df = df[df['Sentiment_B']<0]. But this only extract on the basis of Sentiment_B column. I want something which extract rows where Sentiment_A, Sentiment_B and Sentiment_C all are negative or positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on column condition

Thanks, David for pointing out the type changing.

```
df['Sentiment_B'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Sentiment_B'], errors='coerce')
positive_df = df[df['sentiment_B'>0]] 
nagative_df = df[df['sentiment_B'<0]]
```

More details
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selecting-rows-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-conditions/

Comment: I got the error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'.

Comment: try this first: `df['Sentiment_B'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Sentiment_B'], errors='coerce')`